# Echo within an Echo Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

so I am new to codeigniter and PHP and I have a problem. I can't get the proper syntax to execute an echo within an echo. In my code, the else won't work since I'm using another php code to get the site_url() in codeigniter. Here's the code.

```
<td><?php if($row->homeowner_feedback == 0) {echo "Finished"; } else { echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-3" data-href="<?php echo site_url() . "user_tracking/set_finished_recent/" . $row->ticketid; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Set as Finished</button>'?></td>
```

Comment: You should start by learning php before jumping to php frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.load `url` helper first using `$this->load->helper('url');` in controller.use dot`(.)` for concatenation rateher than nested `echo`.

```
<td><?php if($row->homeowner_feedback == 0)
 {
    echo "Finished";
     } else {
  echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-custom-3' data-href='".base_url()."'/user_tracking/set_finished_recent/".$row->ticketid."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete-modal'>Set as Finished</button>";
  } ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, when you have an if/else that is performing the same function, in this case echo'ing something, you could use this ternary operation instead (Tested).

```
<td>
    <?= ($row->homeowner_feedback == 0)
        ? 'Finished'
        : '<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-3" data-href="' . base_url() . '/user_tracking/set_finished_recent/' . $row->ticketid . ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Set as Finished</button>';
    ?>
</td>
```